# Separate actions in export

Tags: export, .fbx

I have several rigs and animations. I want to export only the current action to .fbx; however, I do not want to delete the others. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Actions (animations) and FBX are a bit tedious… Think what you want is 'scene' animation export (as in, only get 'active' action applied to animated objects)? In this case, you should disable 'All Actions' (and probably also 'NLA') options from Animation tab in FBX export settings.

Answer (score 0):

There are no perfect solutions for now, however here is a workaround:

-Save the file

-Go to the action editor

-Delete the actions you don't want by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and left clicking the <kbd>X</kbd> button to unlink the action (shift will force the unlink even if the armature has keys on this action)

-Export FBX

-Revert the file.